# Cartan subalgebra and Casimir invariants

Tags: group-theory, definition, representation-theory, lie-algebra, invariants

To my understanding, if group $G$ is semisimple, $\mathfrak{g}$ is its Lie algebra, and $\Delta_T=[T,\cdot]$ is the adjoint representation, one can analyze its spectrum with $[T,U]=\lambda U$.
A particularly important value is $R=\inf_{T\in\mathfrak{g}}deg(\lambda=0)$, since there are (at most) **$R$ commuting generators of $\mathfrak{g}$** and **$R$ Casimir invariants**. Now,

- the {$C_1,...,C_R$} commuting generators are the generators of a subalgebra called *Cartan's subalgebra*, which is interesting because its structure constants are zero: $[C_i,C_j]=0 \space\forall \space i,j$;
- the {$H_1,...,H_R$} Casimir invariants are defined by the fact that they commute with all the generators of $\mathfrak{g}$.

My question: are $C_i$ and $H_i$ the same? Maybe under some hypotheses? It seems at least plausible, since they both are $R$ independent operators, and they both have banal commutators.

Comment: No, they are not. Cartans are elements of the algebra, while Casimirs are not

Comment: This is worth asking about at the math.SE. Review su(3) and contrast $\lambda_3, \lambda_8$ to the [quadratic and cubic Casimirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Casimir_operators) thereof; the latter are proportional to the identity.